# Open Layers Views - Separate Data on Page and Block

Tags: views, entities, javascript

I have a typical OpenLayers Locator proximity search on Drupal 7. I can search a map for my locations and that works great.

I also have a Product content type that is referenced to my locations. What I'd like to do is to display a table of products on my page AND a map of their corresponding locations.

How can I display two separate data sources on a single page?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a relationship to the Products entity in the view and then added the Product fields in the View. I then excluded most of the location data. This gave me a Products page with a map of locations!